# PHP contact form with JS validation not sending email

Tags: javascript, php, forms, email

What am I doing wrong here the contact form does not send and email I get an error message "Sorry, error occured this time sending your message." when I fill the form and click send

> index.php

```
    <head>
    <title>Khaleda Rajab + Fahad Al Marzouq</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/flat-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $window = $(window);

$('section[data-type="background"]').each(function(){
    var $bgobj = $(this); // assigning the object
    $(window).scroll(function() {

        // Scroll the background at var speed
        // the yPos is a negative value because we're scrolling it UP!                              
        var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / $bgobj.data('speed')); 

        // Put together our final background position
        var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';

        // Move the background
        $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });

    }); // window scroll Ends

}); 
    </script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="js/validation.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var jump=function(e)
{
       //prevent the "normal" behaviour which would be a "hard" jump
       e.preventDefault();
       //Get the target
       var target = $(this).attr("href");
       //perform animated scrolling
       $('html,body').animate(
       {
               //get top-position of target-element and set it as scroll target
               scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
       //scrolldelay: 2 seconds
       },1000,function()
       {
               //attach the hash (#jumptarget) to the pageurl
               location.hash = target;
       });

}

$(document).ready(function()
{
       $('a[href*=#]').bind("click", jump);
       return false;
});
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <section id="home" data-speed="10" data-type="background">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="media/img/khaleda_rajab_plus_fahad_almarzouq_logo.png" alt="Khaleda Rajab + Fahad AlMarzouq">
        <p>The website is under construction.</p>
        <nav>
        <a href="#contact" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary">Contact Us</a>
        </nav>
        <p class="small">
        Powered by <a href="http://www.cinqomedia.com" target="_blank">Cinqo Media</a>
        </p>
</section>
    <section id="contact" data-speed="6" data-type="background">
        <h1 id="contact">Contact Us</h1>
                <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
        <form name="contactForm" class="form-horizontal" id='contact_form' method="post" action='email.php'>
 <div id='name_error' class='error'>Please enter your name.</div>
 <div>
 <input type='text' name='name' id='name' class="form-control" placeholder="Name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Name'">
 </div>
 <div id='email_error' class='error'>Please enter a valid E-mail address.</div>
 <div>
 <input type='text' name='email' id='email' class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail address" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'E-mail address'">
 <div>
 <div id='subject_error' class='error'>Please enter the subject.</div>
 <div>
 <input type='text' name='subject' id='subject' class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Subject'">
 </div>
 <div id='message_error' class='error'>Please enter your message.</div>
 <div>
 <textarea name='message' id='message' class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Message" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Message'"></textarea>
 </div>
 <div id='mail_success' class='success'>Your message has been sent successfully.</div>
 <div id='mail_fail' class='error'>Sorry, error occured this time sending your message.</div>
 <input type='submit' id='send_message' class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" value='Send'>
 </form>
                </div>          
            </div>
        </section>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/backstretch.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $.backstretch([
      "media/img/cat_eye_mask_bg_1.png"
    , "media/img/cat_eye_mask_bg_2.png"
    , "media/img/cat_eye_mask_bg_3.png"
  ], {duration: 4000, fade: 750});
     </script>

</body>
```

> email.php

```
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] . ' Ajax HTML Contact Form : Demo';
$to = $_REQUEST['omar@cinqomedia.com']; //Recipient's E-mail

$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "rn";
$headers .= "From: " . $_REQUEST['email'] . "rn"; // Sender's E-mail
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "rn";

$message .= 'Name: ' . $_REQUEST['name'] . "<br>";
$message .= $_REQUEST['message'];

if (@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
// Transfer the value 'sent' to ajax function for showing success message.
echo 'sent';
}
else
{
// Transfer the value 'failed' to ajax function for showing error message.
echo 'failed';
}
```

> validation.js

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#send_message').click(function(e){

        //Stop form submission & check the validation
        e.preventDefault();

        // Variable declaration
        var error = false;
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var subject = $('#subject').val();
        var message = $('#message').val();

        // Form field validation
        if(name.length == 0){
            var error = true;
            $('#name_error').fadeIn(500);
        }else{
            $('#name_error').fadeOut(500);
        }
        if(email.length == 0 || email.indexOf('@') == '-1'){
            var error = true;
            $('#email_error').fadeIn(500);
        }else{
            $('#email_error').fadeOut(500);
        }
        if(subject.length == 0){
            var error = true;
            $('#subject_error').fadeIn(500);
        }else{
            $('#subject_error').fadeOut(500);
        }
        if(message.length == 0){
            var error = true;
            $('#message_error').fadeIn(500);
        }else{
            $('#message_error').fadeOut(500);
        }

        // If there is no validation error, next to process the mail function
        if(error == false){
           // Disable submit button just after the form processed 1st time successfully.
            $('#send_message').attr({'disabled' : 'true', 'value' : 'Sending...' });

            /* Post Ajax function of jQuery to get all the data from the submission of the form as soon as the form sends the values to email.php*/
            $.post("email.php", $("#contact_form").serialize(),function(result){
                //Check the result set from email.php file.
                if(result == 'sent'){
                    //If the email is sent successfully, remove the submit button
                     $('#submit').remove();
                    //Display the success message
                    $('#mail_success').fadeIn(500);
                }else{
                    //Display the error message
                    $('#mail_fail').fadeIn(500);
                    // Enable the submit button again
                    $('#send_message').removeAttr('disabled').attr('value', 'Send');
                }
            });
        }
    });    
});
```

Comment: what environment you are using

Comment: @anubhav simple php you can check the live version on http://www.khaledarajabplusfahadalmarzouq.com

Comment: Assuming your JS is correct, your PHP script is returning `failed`. I guess that when you enter your own email you don't get anything in your inbox? Maybe you should try executing it manually and  checking the output or log to see why the `mail` statement fails.

Comment: Any error? check your headers?

Comment: @anubhav this is the error I get "Sorry, error occured this time sending your message."

Comment: you are making mistake while creating headers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your email.php has the specific email address inside the REQUEST global, so its looking for a posted field of your email address. If you want to send to a specific email address just list it in a string like so:

```
<?php
$subject = $_POST['subject'] . ' Ajax HTML Contact Form : Demo';
$to = 'omar@cinqomedia.com'; //Recipient's E-mail

$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "rn";
$headers .= "From: " . $_POST['email'] . "rn"; // Sender's E-mail
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "rn";

$message = 'Name: ' . $_POST['name'] . "<br>";
$message .= $_POST['message'];

if (@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
    // Transfer the value 'sent' to ajax function for showing success message.
    echo 'sent';
}
else
{
    // Transfer the value 'failed' to ajax function for showing error message.
    echo 'failed';
}
```

?>

Also your $message variable hadn't been defined before you started using it so you didn't need the '.=' just an '=' when you first use it.

You might want to consider adding some filters to the data posted.

Comment: Did't work it still says "Sorry, error occured this time sending your message." when I click Send

Comment: Are you working on your local machine? If so your computer may not be setup to send emails, you'll need to setup something like hMailServer, here's a tutorial: http://www.codesynthesis.co.uk/tutorials/local-mail-server-with-hmailserver (alternatively test it on your server)